# How do I hold feature to master with git flow

Tags: git, git-flow

I'm using git-flow workflow in my current project. Basically, I have 4 kinds of branches:

- `master`: Main branch for production purpose
- `staging`: For testing features before production, similar with `release`
- `development`: For development purposes. Feature branches are merged into this branch
- `feature`: For developing features

Let's say my team is developing 2 features in 2 `feature` branches, i.e. `feature/login` and `feature/edit-profile` branch. Based on [this](https://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/) site, `feature` branches must be merged to the `development` branch. And for release purpose, Here I merge `development` to `staging`, then `staging` to `development`.

These 2 features are done, and have been merged to `development` branch. But somehow, my team decide not to release the `feature/edit-profile` feature to the `staging` and `master`. Since the `development` branch is now having changes from that branch, the `feature/edit-profile` branch will be merged to `staging` and `master` if I merge from `development`. How should I do to kinda "hold" some feature?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You have a few options that will work:

1. You don't actually have to release the latest commit on `development`; you could release any commit you wish, by merging that commit ID into `staging` (or re-creating `staging` from that commit). In the best case scenario, **if** `feature/login` was merged into `development` *before* `feature/edit-profile` was merged in, then you could merge that commit ID into `staging`. From your description it sounds like you have a 50/50 chance of this being the case.

If #1 doesn't apply because the features were merged into `development` in the reverse order, some additional options are:

2. You could cut the `staging` branch from the commit on `development` before both features were merged in, and then re-merge the `feature/login` branch into `staging`. If `feature/login` had been rebased and itself includes the other feature's commits, you could just cherry-pick the specific commits from that branch onto `staging`. (If you cherry-pick, consider adding the `-x` option so future readers can see the duplication was intentional.)
3. Another option is you could revert the merge commit that brought in `feature/edit-profile`. This will create a new commit that is the reverse of all the commits brought in by that merge. You could do this either on `development`, or on `staging`, depending on whether you prefer to have that feature only removed from the release, or from everywhere, for now. Later on, if you wish to bring that feature back in, the simplest action is probably to revert the revert. Anytime you are reverting commits, and especially when reverting a revert, I strongly urge you to add an explanation in the revert commit message details, so future readers can follow what happened and why.

Note: if you don't wish to release the feature anytime soon, option #3 is probably best.

There is a nuclear option which would only apply in very specific circumstances:

9. Rewrite `development` to only include the feature you want. You *rarely, if ever* want to do this on shared branches, but I'm listing it here for completeness.